# wordpress theme errors after upgrading from php 5.3 to 5.4.33

Tags: php

I just switched servers for a bunch of wordpress hosted websites. On the old server we had php version 5.3, on the new one we got 5.4.33. The problem is that we're getting a lot of errors after this change and some of errors are pretty hard (for me) to solve. Have a look at the code below please :)

These are the errors that I get:

1. *Notice: Undefined variable: icon in /wp-content/themes/livescore/library/functions-single-match.php on line 138*
2. *Notice: Undefined variable: image in /wp-content/themes/livescore/library/functions-single-match.php on line 145*
3. *Notice: Undefined variable: icon in /wp-content/themes/livescore/library/functions-single-match.php on line 179*
4. *Notice: Undefined variable: image in /wp-content/themes/livescore/library/functions-single-match.php on line 184*

And this is functions-single-match.php below:

```
<?php

function lastMatches( $teamName, $directTeam = '' )

{

    global $wpdb_mysqli;

    $matches = array();

    if ($directTeam)

    {


        $args = array(

            'post_type' => 'matches',

            'post_status' => 'publish',

            'posts_per_page' => 10,

            'meta_query' => array(

                array(

                    'key' => '_live_echipa_gazda',

                    'value' => $directTeam,

                    'compare' => '='

                ),

                array(

                    'key' => '_live_echipa_oaspete',

                    'value' => $teamName,

                    'compare' => '='

                )

            )

        );

    }

    else

    {

        $args = array(

            'post_type' => 'matches',

            'post_status' => 'publish',

            'posts_per_page' => 10,

            'meta_query' => array(

                'relation' => 'OR',

                array(

                    'key' => '_live_echipa_gazda',

                    'value' => $teamName,

                    'compare' => '='

                ),

                array(

                    'key' => '_live_echipa_oaspete',

                    'value' => $teamName,

                    'compare' => '='

                ),

            )

        );

    }









    $query = new WP_Query( $args );



    $matches = $query->posts;



    return $matches;

}



function matchStatusGazde( $matchID )

{

    $statusIstoric = get_post_meta( $matchID, '_live_status_meci_gazde', true );

    $result = new stdClass();
    switch ($statusIstoric)
    {
        case 'v':
             $icon = 'smileyface1.png';
            break;
        case 'e':
           $icon = 'smileyface3.png';
            break;
        case 'i':
           $icon = 'smileyface2.png';
        default:
            break;
    }

    if ($icon)
    {
        $pathImg = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/library/images/$icon";
        $image = "<img src='$pathImg' border='0'/>";

    }


    $result->image = $image;



    return $result;

}





function matchStatusOaspeti( $matchID )

{
    $statusIstoric = get_post_meta( $matchID, '_live_status_meci_oaspeti', true );

    $result = new stdClass();

    switch ($statusIstoric)
    {
        case 'v':
            $icon = 'smileyface1.png';
            break;
        case 'e':
            $icon = 'smileyface3.png';
            break;
        case 'i':
            $icon = 'smileyface2.png';
        default:
            break;

    }
    if ($icon)
    {
        $pathImg = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/library/images/$icon";
        $image = "<img src='$pathImg' border='0'/>";
    }

    $result->image = $image;

    return $result;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are undefined variables due to the way in which unresolved cases are defined.

Both `matchStatusGazde()` and `matchStatusOaspeti()` need to be fixed. Below is an example of one way to do that.

```
function matchStatusOaspeti( $matchID )
{
    $statusIstoric = get_post_meta( $matchID, '_live_status_meci_oaspeti', true );
    $result = new stdClass();
    switch ($statusIstoric)
    {
        case 'v':
            $icon = 'smileyface1.png';
            break;
        case 'e':
            $icon = 'smileyface3.png';
            break;
        case 'i':
            $icon = 'smileyface2.png';
        default:
            // define $icon as false
            $icon = false;
            break;
    }
    // if a case above is not evaluated and there is no default then $icon would not be set and this returns a notice
    if ($icon)
    {
        $pathImg = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/library/images/$icon";
        $image = "<img src='$pathImg' border='0'/>";
    }
    else
    {
        // if $image is only defined if $icon is set then $image would be undefined and this returns a notice
        $image = false; // or '' or 0 depending on how the result is used
    }
    $result->image = $image;
    return $result;
}
```

The most likely cause is not the change of PHP version but the display_errors setting in the php.ini. Ie on the old server the display_errors setting probably didn't include notices, while on the new server it does.

For a production server it is recommended that you use

```
E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

In development you should use

```
E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

So that you can track down these kinds of notices (such as undefined variables) and fix.

You can change the value in the php.ini file or in your code using `ini_set()`

Comment: Thanks Tristan, Unfortunately the problem is that I can't track down the error. In wordpress you can very easy hide all the notices by adding define('WP_DEBUG', false); in wp-config.php Here the problem is that the code is not generating the $image variable and I'm looking to solve that not hide the notice :)

Comment: @AXLwarrior: Well then you should have asked the question accordingly. Tristan’s post is a perfectly fine answer to the question you’ve asked.

Comment: I've edited to show how to fix the undefined variables

Comment: @lxg I'm sorry for not providing all the details in my initial question.

Comment: @Tristan, Indeed your solution solves the notices. Unfortunately my $image variable is still not showing up so I guess there are also some other errors in different files that I need to solve. Thanks anyway, very prompt and very helpful!

Comment: Try checking the value of `$statusIstoric`. The original code assumed it would always be v,e or i, but the notices arose because it was not one of these values.

Comment: It's very confusing for me because on the old server everything works ok while on the new one with PHP 5.4.33 I'm facing this.. I've also checked $statusIstoric but everything seems to be ok